# Flask Sqlalchemy how to not auto-update TIMSTAMP column when update a row

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I have a model:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    created_time = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)
```

However, every time I updated `name` or `password`, the timestamp `created_time` would be updated, but I don't want `created_time` to be updated.

```py
# the way I update a user's info
class UserController(Resource):
    def get(self):
        user = User.query.filter_by(id=1).first()  # a user had been created before
        user.name = "new_name"
        db.session.commit()  
       # as of here, not only `name` but also `created_time` will be update
```

How to stop `created_time` from auto-updating when updating a row?

---

#### Edit 1

To be more precise, I would like to know about the mechanism of `db.TIMESTAMP`, and more specifically, to resolve the issue that when I update other columns in a row `db.TIMESTAMP` column is also updated.

I would instead want the value in `db.TIMESTAMP` column to be fixed at the time the row is created, and that value should never change regardless of how values in other columns change.

P.S. To avoid misunderstanding, I know `TIMESTAMP` may not be the most appropriate type for `created_time` column, but the above code is only for illustrating purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Well, from what I understand, the on_update event trigger which causes your problem is not the default, and it should not be generated without being told explicitly.

see more: [Marking Implicitly Generated Values, timestamps, and Triggered Columns](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#marking-implicitly-generated-values-timestamps-and-triggered-columns)

The Ideal way to create created/modified timestamps is like this

```
class Base():
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now())
    modified_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now(), onupdate=db.func.now())
```

src: [Define Output Column In Flask-Sqlalchemy](https://www.sporule.com/items/define-output-column-in-flask-sqlalchemy)

here I found good references which may help you solve the problem.
[How to stop SQLAlchemy from adding an ON UPDATE clause to a TIMESTAMP column by default](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/3444)

Answer (score 1):

Your column for your `created_time` should be `db.DateTime`.

Comment: Indeed, I just updated a row's info created yesterday and `created_time` wasn't automatically updated. But what if I need `db.TIMESTMP` in other services, is there a way to prevent it from auto-updating?

Comment: `db.TIMESTAMP` isn't actually a column type you'd use in that parameter. `DateTime` is enough and can be timezone aware already. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you!

Comment: You are right. But I will use `db.TIMSTAMP` for other services instead, which I just made it clearer in **Edit 1**. And I encountered the issue I illustrated above. So, changing the type from `db.TIMSTAMP` to `db.DateTime` isn't really solving the problem. I still need to know if there is a way to prevent `db.TIMESTAMP` column from auto-upating its value.